# How to filter by date part in tortoise ORM

Tags: tortoise-orm

I just started using tortoise ORM. And was wondering is it all possible to filter the datetime field by its part. For example to filter out only rows which datetime column corresponds to a given month. Similarly as it is done in Django ORM  that is `.filter(datetime_field__month=6)`

Comment: Just asked a similar question, please post if you know the answer already.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65951082/how-to-use-db-functions-in-tortoise-orm

Answer (score 2):

I have posted response in my question: [How to use db functions in Tortoise ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65951082/how-to-use-db-functions-in-tortoise-orm)

For your problem I suppose your can use `pypika.CustomFunction`, here is a link: https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#custom-functions

Unfortunately, this is only what I can help with, using `pypika.functions.Extract` didn't help me either. My assumption was to do `EXTRACT (MONTH FROM "created_at")` but Tortoise ORM doesn't allow me to put this field in `filter` query.

Answer (score 2):

When you use Tortoise ORM and specify that a field is a DatetimeField, you can access its parts, as for example the month, with datetime_field__month.

This only works with PostgreSQL and MySQL, not with SQLite.

You can find the different parts to which you can access here: https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query.html#filtering

Comment: despite this feature presented in the documentation It doesn't work for me in version 0.6.3. raising error: `'int' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'`. could you provide some solutions on this issue?

Comment: sorry, my tortoise-orm version is 0.19.2

Comment: I was getting error because my tortoise orm's confs `use_tz=True`. Instead of this we can you `created_at__startswith='2022-07'` for example