# How to use db functions in Tortoise ORM

Tags: python, sql, database, psql, tortoise-orm

I am trying to write a simple query but using PSQL functions CURRENT_DATE and INTERVAL, for instance:

```py
users = await User.filter(created_at__gt="CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 DAYS'")
```

How to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Tortoise ORM processes different queries differently.
For instance:

- for `update` query you can use just a string value:

```py
await User.filter(id=user_id).update(updated_at="now()")
```

- for `filter` queries you can use `pypika.functions` and `pypika.terms`
  For instance:

```py
from pypika.terms import Parameter, Interval

await User.filter(created_at__gte=Parameter("CURRENT_DATE") - Interval(days=30))
```

- for `create` queries it's very tricky. Tortoise ORM is not built for that and what you need to do is to make your own field type class by inheriting from `tortoise.fields.data.DateField` or `tortoise.fields.data.DateTimeField` and override `to_db_value` method.

Long story short, it is possible but very tricky, especially if you want to use all 3 types of queries: CREATE, UPDATE and SELECT.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypika'

Comment: That's odd, Tortoise uses `pypika-tortoise` as a dependency, so it should be installed together with your tortoise package: https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/blob/develop/pyproject.toml#L38.      Could you check your package folder? This is the pypika package: https://github.com/tortoise/pypika-tortoise/tree/main/pypika

Comment: @andnik would you happen to know how to query a `ArrayField` in Postgres created using `from tortoise.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField`? I posted a question here if you know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73192631/tortoise-orm-how-to-query-a-postgres-arrayfield-from-contrib-postgres-fields

Comment: Response in your link.